# How to merge or move two vertices without affecting the others?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I want to merge two vertices into one, but Blender help me to select the third one automatically. I didn't turn one Proportional Editing Mode. Would anyone here can explain why? Please go to my shared videos below to see my problem in detail, if my word is not clear enough. Thank you

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7o5ywq5dlOgOFNVVHhkZzljcjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Remember that it's possible to Hide (Ctrl H) the selected vertices, so then they will be out of your way and you can select the third one. There are many solutions, but this is a simple one. Oh, and Alt H to un-hide when you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see, you are using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **mouse click** instead <kbd>Shift</kbd> + **mouse click**  for selecting multiple vertexes.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **mouse click** is a **Pick Shortest Path** function and select road from vertex to vertex.

To add vertex to selection use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + **mouse click**

[image]

Comment: You are right. Thank you for you rapid reply~